# Rounding and thousand separator in pandas dataframe: cannot get rid of decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I've to use pandas v0.16.2 (!) and I'm stuck with some basic formatting.

How can I get rid of the decimal places and apply thousand separator in the 'val' column below. Here is my attempt which still ends up with one decimal.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['abc', 'bvn'],'val' : [100000.1234,2000000.1234]})
df['val'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: '{:,}'.format(np.round(x,0)))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `round()` function returns a floating point number, which means you'll still get that decimal in the string representation.

```py
>>> round(3.1)
3.0
```

An easy way to get rid of the decimal is to cast it to an integer:

```py
>>> int(round(3.1))
3
```

In your code, this would be:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['abc', 'bvn'],'val' : [100000.1234,2000000.1234]})
df['val'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: '{:,}'.format(int(np.round(x,0))))
print(df)
```